# How to Exclude a Model Field and Include a Computed Attribute in Tortoise ORM Pydantic Schema?

Tags: fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm, pydantic-v2

I'm working with Tortoise ORM in a FastAPI project and have a `Channel` model which optionally includes a password hash when channel is protected. I want to generate a list of channels for API responses, where I exclude the `password_hash` field and include a new computed boolean field, `protected`, to indicate whether a channel is password protected.

Here's the model definition:

```py
from tortoise import fields, models
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import pydantic_model_creator

class Channel(models.Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    password_hash = fields.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    owner = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.User', related_name='channels')

ChannelSchema = pydantic_model_creator(Channel, name="Channel")
```

Current API response example:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "my channel",
    "password_hash": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "my protected channel",
    "password_hash": "$2b$..."
  }
]
```

Desired API response:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "my channel",
    "protected": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "my protected channel",
    "protected": true
  }
]
```

How can I correctly include the `protected` computed attribute in my Pydantic model while excluding the `password_hash` field?

I attempted to create a computed attribute `password_protected` and exclude `password_hash` like so:

```py
class Channel(models.Model):
    ...
    
    def password_protected(self) -> bool:
        return bool(self.password_hash)

    class PydanticMeta:
        computed = ["password_protected"]
        # exclude = ["password_hash"]
```

However, excluding `password_hash` leads to an error:

```
AttributeError: 'ResponseChannelSchema' object has no attribute 'password_hash'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this problem, using the `serialize_password` method for serialization, and `serialization_alias`.

```py
class ResponseChannelSchema(ChannelSchema):
    password_hash: str | None = Field(None, serialization_alias="protected")

    @field_serializer('password_hash')
    def serialize_password(self, v: str) -> bool:
        return bool(v)
```